# Convert old StarOffice Writer 3 file to a readable document

Tags: ubuntu, conversion, libreoffice

I have an old SDW 3.0 Document which mostly only contains text, but the binary form seems to have no plain text included.

Also LibreOffice after 4.0 does not support that in reading anymore. 
In Ubuntu 12 this was libreoffice-filter-binfilter package.

So I am looking for a SDW 2 TXT (or ODT ...) converter for Ubuntu 14 and later

Comment: Maybe the `openoffice.org-base` package still does?

Comment: Worst case: temporarily install an old version of OpenOffice or LibreOffice to translate the files to a current format.

Comment: see also https://superuser.com/questions/1065973/how-to-open-staroffice-writer-files-in-os-x and https://superuser.com/questions/90166/how-do-i-read-old-star-office-5-x-spreadcheet-documents-today-sdc