# How to open StarOffice Writer files in OS X

Tags: macos, openoffice, libreoffice

I came across some old StarOffice Writer (`.sdw`) files that I *really* would like to open.

I have tried opening them with Apache Open Office and LibreOffice. The first one doesn't seem to support `.sdw` files anymore, and LibreOffice freezes every time I try to open the file.

I have searched for solutions online, but I haven't been able to find any help for OS X. The whole matter seems pretty obscure these days.

Unfortunately, I don't have access to an old copy of StarOffice on a CD or anything like that. Would anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like LibreOffice dropped support for StarOffice files after version `3.6.7.2`.

I downloaded LibreOffice `3.6.7.2` from their [old binaries archive](https://downloadarchive.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/old/) and opened the file, and then exported to `ods` and `pdf`, worked fine.

LibreOffice `3.6.7.2` was released in 2013.